# http.nonProxyHosts ignored on localhost only

Tags: java, http, proxy, localhost

I run a proxy on localhost:2080 for debugging purposes. I can see trafic going through my proxy using either:

```
curl http://localhost:8888/stuff --proxy localhost:2080
curl http://some.server.com:8888/stuff --proxy localhost:2080
```

Using a Spring application, or a bare bones [HttpURLConnectionExample Java application](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/), I see requests go through the proxy when I call `some.server.com`, but never on `localhost`, even though I set `http.nonProxyHosts` to a random value (to avoid the default of `localhost`).

I made sure my JVM arguments were taken into accounts by adding the following code:

```
System.out.println("java.version="+props.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println("http.proxyHost="+props.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
System.out.println("http.proxyPort="+props.getProperty("http.proxyPort"));
System.out.println("http.nonProxyHosts="+props.getProperty("http.nonProxyHosts"));
```

That produces the following output:

```
java.version=1.8.0_131
http.proxyHost=localhost
http.proxyPort=2080
http.nonProxyHosts=dummy.snafu.com
https.proxyHost=localhost
https.proxyPort=2080
https.nonProxyHost=dummy.snafu.com
Testing 1 - Send Http GET request

Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://localhost:8888/stuff
Response Code : 200
hello
```

Why are HTTP requests to `localhost` not going through my proxy when run with the following JVM arguments?

- `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost`
- `-Dhttp.proxyPort=2080`
- `-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=dummy.snafu.com`

Comment: Have you checked the value of `nonProxyHosts` from within the client application?

Comment: Yes, thanks for asking. Added relevant code and output to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of DefaultProxySelector, It always appends local Uris(localhost, 127.*, etc) to whatever you configure as nonProxyHosts, essentially bypassing proxy for all local Uris(localhost|127. *|[::1]|0.0.0.0|[::0]). Fortunately, there is a workaround by creating your own proxy selector and registering it as default.

Comment: I have made it working by implementing a simple proxy selector (few lines of code), let me know if you need sample. This is useful for local traffic tracing by fiddler, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I ended up using Proxy-Vole https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole